# How can I scatter things apart?

Tags: animation, origin

How can I select multiple objects and spread their origins apart from each other without scaling the objects themselves? I have several fragments of a shape that I want together at the first keyframe and all of the pieces separated at the last keyframe. I don't want to use the logic engine to do this. Is this possible?

Comment: The same as here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/separate-two-objects-along-an-axis

Comment: @lemon Thank you for that, couldn't find that when googling around.